# Modify then display page using C#

Tags: c#, http, proxy

Can someone point me in the right direction for implementing proxy-like behavior with C#?
I'm looking to catch `HTTP` requests from a site, parse, then modify the `DOM` and show the results. Ideally, this program would run as a proxy on the local machine, but I'm fine with implementing a custom "browser" if needed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you want a process on the local machine, so how about a Browser Helper Object (BHO)?  You should be able to intercept the content before it's rendered and modify it in any way you want.  I've only done them in ATL, but a bit of research indicates a C# version is possible.

Answer (score 2):

What about writing an [extension](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/) for [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?